# Cannot read property 'params' of undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new to React. I'm trying to pass a value through URL using `react-router-dom`. But unable to get the params getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined.

I tried the solutions that already present but nothing help. What is the mistake I did?  Can someone explain it to me? Thanks in advance.

`Main` Component:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/edit/:id" component={Edit} exact={true}>
            <Edit />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

`Edit` Component:

```
class Edit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: this.props.match.params.id
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <h2>Edit Page</h2>;
  }
}
export default Edit;
```

Comment: console log `this.props` and check whether the `match` key exists in it or not?

Comment: and please mention the full link which you are using for edit.

Comment: I'm getting empty object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** I provided my answer with `useParams` since your original question was involving it. Other than that if you have to use a class component, normally `this.props.match.params.id` should work since you are using your component via a `Route`.

You should use `useParams` in your `Edit` component and it should be a function component.

```
function Edit() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <div>{id}</div>
  )
}
```

Also, I don't know which React Router version you use, but if you are not using v6, you probably want to use the Route part like this:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/edit/:id" component={Edit} exact />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Thank you, working fine with class component alone by removing component from in-between route tag.

Comment: By changing this to `<Route path="/edit/:id" component={Edit} exact={true}><Edit /></Route>` this  `<Route path="/edit/:id" component={Edit} exact={true}></Route>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Edit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: this.props.match.params.id
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <h2>Edit Page</h2>;
  }
}
export default withRouter(Edit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to check your react version because your code just ran fine in my system - Edited your Edit component

```
return (
            <>
            <h2>Edit Page</h2>
            {this.state.id}
            </>
        );
```

accessed url - http://localhost:3000/edit/:2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ0FW.png)

result in image

Comment: I'm using 16.13.0